# Model deployment failing in azure machine learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am following the procedure as described [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/02/deploy-your-ml-model-as-a-web-service-in-microsoft-azure-cloud/).
I am trying to register models and deploy them in Azure machine learning. I have the following script:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import sklearn
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    import pickle
    import joblib
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    dataset = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", header = None, names= colnames )
    dataset = dataset.replace({"class":  {"Iris-setosa":1,"Iris-versicolor":2, "Iris-virginica":3}})
    X = dataset.drop(['class'], axis=1)[:,0]
    y = dataset['class']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
    classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
    #Fit the model on training data
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #Make the prediction
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    ## Save as a pickle file
    filename= 'final_mod_v1.pkl'
    joblib.dump(classifier,open(filename, 'wb'))
```

In the models tab I registered the model. Then I tried to deploy the model as web service. The following is the scoring script file.

```py
    import json
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import pickle
    import joblib
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from azureml.core import Model
    
    def init():
        global model
        model_name = 'classifier'
        path = Model.get_model_path(model_name)
        model = joblib.load(path)
    
    def run(data):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            result = model.predict(data['data'])
            return {'data' : result.tolist() , 'message' : "Successfully classified Iris"}
    
        except Exception as e:
            error = str(e)
            return {'data' : error , 'message' : 'Failed to classify iris'}
```

The following is the **conda_dependencies.yml**:

```
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.6.2
- pip:
  - pandas==1.1.5
  - azureml-defaults
  - joblib==0.17.0
- scikit-learn==0.23.2
name: azureml_2d0fd20031db3baaed8684d5f08fe619
```

I am confused about the last line in the above script `azureml_2d0fd20031db3baaed8684d5f08fe619`

```
 name: azureml_2d0fd20031db3baaed8684d5f08fe619
```

The deployment is failing. Deployment log shows:

```
 container "classifier" in pod "wk-caas-9a4c565844b043cfa9d8ba246af11ff5-517e6d8f74175a01ffc43147e5dd8133-pod" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

It would be helpful if I can get a guidance on this.